# C# printing blank Document when using for loop

Tags: c#

I'm having issue with printing more pages in C# project.
if i print one page only it prints normal, but when using for loop to all pages in the document, it shows up all pages in the printpreviewcontrol but when print them or save them as PDF they come out blank.
when try to print one page or  one line the printout normal.
I appreciate your help.
this is the  code:

```
   int line = -1; 
  private void printDocument2_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
  {
     Font f = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Regular);

     e.HasMorePages = false;
   int  currentHight = 0;

     line++;
     for (; line < textBox1.Lines.Count(); line++)
     {
        //Lines[line]locates the current line position in the page
        e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Lines[line], f, Brushes.Blue, 30, currentHight +50);
        currentHight += f.Height;

        if (currentHight >= e.PageBounds.Height - 150)
        {
           e.HasMorePages = true;
           break;
        }

     }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure line =0 when you start the for loop?

Comment: yes, it initiates with -1  out the Document method and it become line=0 with the code line++; ... when try without the for loop it prints  normally, but when use the loop the print out come blank.

Comment: Make sure to reset all relevant variables, like `line` etc..!